How can I find time constant of a RC circuit with a transistor circuit when switch is closed?

First of all maybe this a easy question but I am a beginner, so forgive me. I am having trouble finding the time constant shown in the circuit. How we analyze this?

Welcome! If you start by ignoring the R2 and Q1 all together, what time constant do you have?

Hi and thank you:) I have V0.e^(-t/rc) time constant if i ignored  r2 and q1 . Also i updated my question. Maybe it was missing.

Wait a minute. Is this a trick question or is the R1 supposed to be above the horizontal connection to R2?

When i push button, capacitor is charging. If i release the button capacitor is discharging and supplying transistor. That is all.

Sure, but is the schematic from you? As drawn, it would light up immediately but turn off a short while after letting it go. Is this desired?

Yes. schematic is my and it works as you say. Just i want to find Vc(t) function and time constant when switch is off state.

Good. What voltage will C2 charge up to? When you let go, how much current would initially flow though R1, R2 and base of Q1? With that initial current and known capacitor size, what will the time constant be?

C2 will charge up to 12V .

C2 will charge to 12V if the button is pressed very very long time. Tau=5sec and count with 10Tau at least.

When the switch is closed (conducting) you get
\$\tau_{on}=R1\cdot C2\$
When it is open (not conducting) you get
\$\tau_{off} = (R1+R2)\cdot C2 \$, ignoring Vbe.
Since Vbe << 12V, ignoring Vbe is a reasonable assumption. A capacitor of that size will likely have a wide tolerance anyway.
But keep in mind that time constant alone won't necessarily reliably predict the time for D2 to turn off after the switch is released even if you assume the switch is held for a very long time (relative to the time constant) so that C2 is fully charged. Time constant is the time it takes the capacitor to charge or discharge to 1-1/e or about 63% of the final voltage change.
The time to appear 'off' will also be dependent on transistor hFE and R5 since it won't start to go off until the transistor goes out of saturation. It might be a couple time constants before it starts to go off, and because of physiological response (and especially in subdued lighting) it might be several (or many) more time constants before the LED appears to be 'off' entirely.
Also if you're attempting to estimate the above, note that the capacitor is discharging towards a slightly variable Vbe rather than ground. This will be quite important if you are looking to estimate the time  when a very low diode current such as 50uA or 100uA will occur.

By the looks of it you're traing to get a delay for switching off.
When you press the button, the LED lights up immediately, when you release the the button, the LED stays lit for some time and than slowly fades out.
With the circuit shown you get two different time constants for charging and discharging.
For Charging we can ignore R2 since we're connecting R1 directly to the voltage source via the switch:
$$\tau = R1 * C2$$
For discharging we should be good with ignoring Vbe of Q1 and just assume it as 0 Ohms. And thus we're dischargin the capacitor via R1 in series to R2:
$$ \tau = (R1 + R2) * C2$$

Alright Do Vbe voltage effect to the  time constant?

@kruemi - please, can you explain WHY you think that we have two different time constants for charging resp. discharging?

My former comment assumes that the switch is closed all the time (as statet by the TO). When "charging" means "switch closed" and "discharging" means "switch open", both time constants are different - however, the above given values for tau are not correct. In both cases, the path through the B-E junction of the transistor is missing.

Since Vbe can be assumed to be a constant voltage (if we're not assuming that, we can forget about calculating it and simulation is the only path left), it's just an offset. So no, it does not have an effect on the time constant of the RC-Circuit. If you want to take it into consideration, just use V0-700mV.
